# How to catch Mobx observable updates in persistent NextJS React Audio Player component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mobx, server-side-rendering

I have a server side rendered audio player react app.

Using [NextJS' custom _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-app), I have a persistent AudioPlayer component, in which I want to call an internal `this.play(mp3url)` function whenever the `@observable playerData = {}` changes in the mobx store.

I have successfully made button clicks on other components in my app update playerData whenever required.

But I am unable to detect these updates inside my AudioPlayer component, so that I can set its state and call `this.play(mp3url)` to start playing the audio.

**pages/_app.js**

```
import initializeStore from '../stores/stores';

export default class MyApp extends App {

  static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
    const mobxStore = initializeStore();
    appContext.ctx.mobxStore = mobxStore;
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
    return {
      ...appProps,
      initialMobxState: mobxStore,
    };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mobxStore = props.initialMobxState;
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider {...this.mobxStore}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        { this.mobxStore.playerStore.playerActive && <AudioPlayer /> }
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**components/AudioPlayer.js**

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'

@inject('playerStore')
@observer
class Player extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            url: null,
            image: null
        }
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            url: nextProps.playerStore.playerData.url,
            image: nextProps.playerStore.playerData.image
        }, () => { this.play(this.state.url) })
    }

    // ...Other react-player functions

    render() {
        <ReactPlayer 
        {/* ...required props... */}
        />
    }
}
```

> So how would one get this persistent audio player to detect changes in the
>   mobx observable to play audio urls?

As of now, `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` do not get called. `componentDidMount` gets called exactly once as expected when I set `@observable playerActive = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. It was caused by **two issues**.

1. As per the Mobx docs

> The observer function / decorator can be used to turn ReactJS components into reactive components. It wraps the component's render function in mobx.autorun to make sure that any data that is used during the rendering of a component forces a re-rendering upon change. It is available through the separate mobx-react package.

A store observable needs to be used in the render function of the observer component for the component to react to its changes. So I added them in the AudioPlayer Component instead of taking it from its own state.

2. I was missing this crucial line of code in the `pages/_app.js` constructor that would have initialised the mobx store correctly on the client side.

```
this.mobxStore = isServer ? props.initialMobxState : initializeStore(props.initialMobxState)
```

Now the AudioPlayer component reacts to each update to the mobx observable and I am able to handle any further needed logic in `componentWillUpdate`/`componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your example. I have a working website on music that I want to turn into React. To preserve my SEO advantages, I switched the test of React Router to NextJS. But I definitely need that audio player never stop across pages. I'll check this and contact you if I need help.

Comment: Yes I did, once I put the Player in the `_app.js`, NextJS will never get rid of it. So I use function props with events on `_app.js` to update the player whenever I need